# Oracle database real-time backup + auto switchover

Tags: database, oracle, oracle11g, backup

I am a newbie to database administration. I am trying to get things sorted out but as I study more and more about oracle database backup I get more messed up, so I've decided to ask here. Please accept my apologize if I say something ridiculous :p.

Here is my "simple" situation 1:
[image]

Assuming I have 2 server rack, one is my **Primary Server**, another is my **Backup Server** (Both server sitting in the same site).(Using Oracle 11g), When the Primary Database broke down, the primary database service will point to backup database. Therefore, the backup database must always be updated from primary database, like a mirror. So my questions are:

1. What backup method suits this situation? Oracle Dataguard? Oracle Stream? Oracle Goldengate?
2. Can Oracle Active Dataguard achieve this approach?
3. If Oracle Active Dataguard can achieve this, the redo-log will only be applied when there is a switchover? So if the primary database broke down and the redo-log only starts to apply into the backup database, I'll have some downtime before my production can resume? This production requires 0 downtime.

Please feel free to comment on the database architecture base on the following requirements and feel free to change it if it is not correct.

Requirements:

- No downtime. The site is running 24/7.
- Auto switchover to backup database without human interaction.
- Able to notify administrator after switchover (If the switchover is completely transparent, no one will realize something went wrong with the primary database right?)

Thank you so much.

P/s: Sorry for my horrible english.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per your requirements, Oracle data guard is the best solution. Oracle goldengate uses replication concept. Oracle data guard is purely for high availability. There are various protection modes exist in data guard. You can set protection mode for minimum data loss. During Active data guard, standby database (here on backup server as per your detail) is also available for querying and executing read only operations like generating reports. This feature is used for decreasing load on production (here primary server). During this stage, your standby database (backup server) is open in read only mode and also accepting changes (redo) from primary database. It means, it is still updating in background and syncing. There is very minimum chance of data loss and minimum downtime during this stage. Using dataguard, you can set automated switchover task too.

In older versions of Oracle (prior to 11g), if we open standby database in read only mode then it does not accept changes from primary database. If primary database will crash in this situation then we need to apply all changes to standby database manually and wait for data synchronization after that we can switch.

You need to study your technical requirements, consider your IT budget for using these features because Oracle dataguard is license product.

Comment: Hi doc123, first of all, thank you so much for your reply!

I understand that when standby database open in read only mode it will still accept redo from primary database, but how frequent does the redo applies? Everytime when I have some changes commit into primary database it goes into the redo log, then redo log will be pushed to standby database immediately?

Comment: It depends on your protection mode, hardware of server and recovery setting of standby database server.

Comment: Ok that means I'll be able to do so with the Maximum Protection protection mode right? Thanks for clarifying :D

Comment: Always use recovery_parallelism for speeding up recovery process and remember it should not greater than PARALLEL_MAX_SERVERS parameter at standby database side.